# iOS Force splitViewController to rotate to Landscape

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I have a split view controller that supports both landscape and portrait modes. When the detail view controller is on a certain view, I disable portrait and only allow landscape orientation. However, if the user leaves that specific view, rotates the device to portrait, and then returns to that specific view, it is still in portrait. I need to it auto rotate back to landscape. Below is what I am using. These methods are all called from my subclassed UISplitViewController so that the orientation can be view controller dependent.

```
#pragma mark - Orientation

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    // Allow view controller to rotate between landscapes
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    // Return supported interface orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    // Return preferred orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This has worked for me - assumes ARC is enabled

- (void)forceLandscape
{
    UIDevice  *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if([myDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
    {
        NSInteger param     = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
        NSMethodSignature *signature  = [[myDevice class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)];
        NSInvocation      *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
        [invocation setTarget:myDevice];
        [invocation setSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)];
        [invocation setArgument:&param
                        atIndex:2];
        [invocation invoke];
    }
}
```